# How to prevent the bookmarklet from auto reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, seo, bookmarklet

I am trying out this bookmarklet

```
javascript:window.prompt("Title: " +document.title.length+ "/69\n\n" +document.title+ "\n\nCopy Title to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",document.title);
```

I am trying to get the title of the page displayed along with a character count and an easy way to copy it to the clipboard but for some reason after it shows the required info , the page reloads

Any ideas as to why this might be the case ?

Comment: UPDATE :  this should resolve the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796004/how-to-prevent-bookmarklet-from-loading-its-result?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

add void(0) to the end of your bookmarklet

> javascript:window.prompt("Title: " +document.title.length+ "/69\n\n"
>   +document.title+ "\n\nCopy Title to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",document.title);void(0);